# How to capture the PDDoc created by the DoCmd.Output event

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf-generation, reporting, acrobat

Does anybody have an idea on how to capture the event where MS Access (2013) creates the PDDoc or AVDoc for any report that is created as a PDF using the Do.Cmd function ?

For example...

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptReportName", acFormatPDF, _
"FullPathAndFileName.pdf", False
```

Goal:
to create a report -a re-imbursementform- and attach the relevant invoices (scanned) to the report when creating it.

Options:
I understand that there is always the route to create/save the report first and then open and manipulate using the Acrobat IAC and add the invoices afterwards, but that is not the goal...:-)

The report itself creates 'separate' pages for different currencies when/if applicable, so I would like to include the invoices behind the relevant 'currency' pages(s). So, when the report is created I can determine how many pages there are for every currency, I can then, as a separate routine, add in the corresponding invoices, after the report page(s) and continue with the next currency.

Mind you, the quest is to identify **if** you could capture the PDDoc upon its creation from within VBA access? i.e. when 'saving' a report to PDF?
More to make my code 'cleaner'.

I can create the report and add the invoices, but the code will be somewhat messy with regard to determining after which page to insert the invoices.

Comment: I have a reporting tool where I do something similar. The method I chose is to create a temporary folder that is hidden and export all my pdf components there.  I generate unique file names and use a Collection to keep track of the order. Once I've finished exporting all the components, I use the Acrobat api to load and stitch them together to create the final, visible report at a location chosen by the user.  As far as I know it is impossible to grab the PDDoc from Access - the only control you have over the situation is the choice of the file location.

Comment: GD Blackhawk,

Many thanks for your hint, I'd figured as much as I couldn't find any doc's on the subject.